# <epubreder in mono touch using C#>

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, xml-parsing, opf3

i want **epubreder source code in mono touch c# for iPad**  i got it in Xcode but need to convert in c#...
problem of conversion is that i want to parse the container.xml to get the .opf file path and again parse the .opf file.... 
can any one please help me out to solve this problem...

```
public void parseXMLFileAt(string strUrl)
        {

            try
             {
                NSMutableDictionary dict=new NSMutableDictionary();
                  XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("/Users/krunal/Desktop/container.xml");
                string strAttribute=""; 
                while (reader.Read())
                     {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                          {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            Hashtable attributes = new Hashtable();
                            string strURI= reader.NamespaceURI;
                            string strName= reader.Name;
                            if (reader.HasAttributes)
                             {
                                  for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
                                     {
                                            reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                                    attributes.Add(reader.Name,reader.Value);









                                     }
                             }  

                        parser(_parser,strUrl,strURI,strName,dict);


enter code here

StartElement(strURI,strName,strName,attributes);
                      break;

                     default:
                     break;
                         }
                     }
            }
             catch (XmlException e)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("error occured: " + e.Message);
              }

        }
```

**Thanks in advance**